# is there a shortcut for toggle between default screen layout and composit screen layout?

Tags: workflow

i click a lot on the two screen layouts , composite and default. 
every click that i do often,  i try to find a shortcut for it. 
but i doubt there is a shortcut for screen layouts ?
i have not seen a Phyton code showing up at these places.
or am i missing something ?
is there a way to get this shortcut ?
in the worst case i will just keep on clicking each time. 
 but i prefer the shortcut.
i hope anyone has an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to go to composite from Default, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to go back.

Comment: ok that worked perfect, thanks... but i had to first switch off my mission control shortcuts on my macbook. that is why it didn't worked at first !